# hide and unhide dependent drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've made a custom select menu

```
    <span class="depend">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 car-finder-form__input-value" data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--one">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value" data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--two">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value"  data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--three">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 3</a>
        </div>
     </span>
```

here is the dropdown

```
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--one hide">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
                <a href="">bla bla</a>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--two hide">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
                <a href="">bla bla</a>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--three hide">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
                <a href="">bla bla</a>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
```

my jQuery currently looks like this

```
jQuery("div.finder-form__input-value").on("click", function(){
                        var drpdwn = $(this).data("select-dropdown");
                        $(drpdwn).toggleClass("hide");
                    });
```

The jQuery unhides the 1st dropdown menu when clicked. and hides it again when clicked.

But how would i make it close the 1st dropdown when i click on the 2nd dropdown? Close the 2nd dropdown when i click on the 3rd? And close the 2nd and 3rd, when i click on the 1st?

Comment: I think the problem is, $(this) because $(this) gives you the current html element. You can try this;

$(".finder-form--two").toggleClass("hide");

Comment: here is a usefull jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb5qqnto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:not` to hide all dropdowns that don't have the class in the `data-select-dropdown` and then toggle the selected dropdown

```js
jQuery("div.finder-form__input-value").on("click", function() {
  var drpdwn = $(this).data("select-dropdown");
  $('.finder-form__dropdown:not(' + drpdwn + ')').addClass('hide');
  $(drpdwn).toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="depend">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value" data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--one">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value" data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--two">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value"  data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--three">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 3</a>
        </div>
     </span>


<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--one hide">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
      <a href="">bla bla one</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--two hide">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
      <a href="">bla bla tow</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--three hide">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
      <a href="">bla bla three</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the element has the class .hide as default, you can change your jQuery as follows:

```
jQuery("div.finder-form__input-value").on("click", function(){
  $("div:not(.hide)").addClass("hide"); /* hides the menu that's open */
  var drpdwn = $(this).data("select-dropdown");
  $(drpdwn).toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand the question correctly, I think you want to have one dropdown open which is clicked and rest of them have them closed. For that you need to apply the hide class to all and then have one of them open which is clicked.

```
$("div.finder-form__input-value").on("click", function() {
  var drpdwn = $(this).data("select-dropdown");
  $('.finder-form__dropdown').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  })
  $(drpdwn).removeClass('hide');
});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nzynxjgj/

Answer (score 0):

> But how would i make it close the 1st dropdown when i click on the 2nd dropdown? Close the 2nd dropdown when i click on the 3rd? And close the 2nd and 3rd, when i click on the 1st?

I'm not sure why you would do it like this. However, you would have to adapt your jQuery code a bit to distinguish which element was clicked and to decide which ones to hide.

```
$("div.finder-form__input-value").on("click", function(){
    const dd = $(this).data("select-dropdown");
    // Here dd will contain the class name of the dropdown.

    if( dd == ".finder-form--one" ) {
        // Clicked first => close second and third.
        $(dd).toggleClass("hide");
        $(".finder-form—two").addClass("hide");
        $(".finder-form—three").addClass("hide");
    } else if( dd == ".finder-form--two" ) {
        // Clicked second => close first.
        $(".finder-form—one").addClass("hide");
        $(dd).toggleClass("hide");
    } else if( dd == ".finder-form--three" ) {
        // Clicked third => close second.
        $(".finder-form—two").addClass("hide");
        $(dd).toggleClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

lets say you have 3 divs in the menu, and for each div in the menu you want to have a drop down menu ( I will use divs for elemtnts in menu & drop downs):

```
<div class='menu-wrapper'>

    <div class='firstChoice'><div class='firstDRDWN'>bla bla</div><div>
    <div class='secondChoice'><div class='secondDRDWN'>bla bla</div><div>
    <div class='thirdChoice'><div class='thirdDRDWN'>bla bla</div><div>

</div>
```

now your jQuery should be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

/*    HIDE ALL OF THE DROP DOWNS WHEN THE PAGE LOADS    */

$('.firstDRDWN').hide();
$('.secondDRDWN').hide();
$('.thirdDRDWN').hide();

/*   NOW SET THE FUNCTION FOR EACHE OF THE ELEMENTS IN YOUR MENU    */

    $('.firstChoice')on('click', function(){

        $('.firstDRDWN').show();
        $('.secondDRDWN').hide();
        $('.thirdDRDWN').hide();

    });

    $('.secondChoice')on('click', function(){

        $('.firstDRDWN').hide();
        $('.secondDRDWN').show();
        $('.thirdDRDWN').hide();

    });

    $('.thirdChoice')on('click', function(){

        $('.firstDRDWN').hide();
        $('.secondDRDWN').hide();
        $('.thirdDRDWN').show();

    });
}
```

Here You reference every button separately, and trigger functions that will hide all drop downs except the one clicked, that will be shown.